# How do I create a page that is responsive based on height not width?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to create a very simple page for a game that I will embed using an iframe.

> **the game and text resize should always scale to fit *the height* of your screen**, and when the window gets really small, it just shows the game (which makes sense)

> My game will be embedded using an iframe and is 3:4 in size.

> I've found lots of examples which show how to do width, but none that focus on height.

I've been playing around with this example, but no luck so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/mjgLcp9q/

```
<div class="responsive-video">
<div class="cta"></div>div>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/j1qtsLfZWWQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

```
.responsive-video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /*Set based on the videos aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio is 16:9 set 
    the padding bottom to 56.25%. If the video aspect ration is 4:3, set padding-bottom to 75% */
    padding-top: 35px; /*Height of the youtube video header*/
    height: 0; /* Not needed as the iframe derives the height from the padding bottom */
    overflow: hidden; /*hides if any of the video escapes outside the container*/
}
.cta  {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.responsive-video iframe {
    width: 100%; /*make sure video takes up 100% of the width*/
    height: 100%;/*make sure video takes up 100% of the height*/
    position: absolute; /*required because container has a height of 0*/
    left: 0; /* correct the positioning */
    top: 0; /* correct the positioning */
}
```

Comment: You utilize media queries with CSS, you can make your design responsive to all sorts of different resolutions. Check this out. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. Do not just write all your CSS inside media-queries,  they're used to over-ride attributes of specific ID/classes when size requirements are met.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to coding, by chance do you know any tutorial or example? ... I'm finding it very hard to find an example on positonining an iframe embed + text line below, so it always perfectly fills the screen vertically as much as it can (while maintaining aspect ratio) just like the link example above.

Comment: Hope the example helps, not always will you need media-queries but it'll be very useful to learn how to use or at least use the common sizes to start.

Comment: @Yogi  - there's a learning for me then! i have a game (made using construct) i want to put on the page. it exports the files as html5. iframe is the only way i know how to implement, but if canvas is a better way I am happy to learn that too. If any recommends where to look

Comment: @BGPHiJACK i am going to take a look and give it a go right now. thank you so much for your kind help. let you know how i get on.

Comment: It's a whole new world of hurt but once you're comfortable it really improves your design. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick write up, I imagine there may be mistakes but this demonstrates how media-query can be valuable but not necessarily needed in your case for all aspects. It's powerful in cases you want to take things from desktop viewing to mobile viewing and want to adjust sizing and all sorts.

Below is the example.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

#text {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Media query for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #text {
        display: none; /* Hide the text on screens below 600px width */
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Iframe with Text</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
    <div id="text">
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the example to run properly, you may need to zoom-in to the browser or change the window size manually to make window think it's 600px or below.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.iframe-container {
    /* Define your desired aspect ratio here (e.g., 16:9) */
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    width: 80%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

#text {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Media query for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #text {
        display: none; /* Hide the text on screens below 600px width */
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Iframe with Text</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps this will explain it. Aspect-ratio can be applied. Minor adjustments to the HTML structure as we must wrap the iframe to do this.

Comment: thank you again so much. i'm going to give this a try - think stackoverflow was done for a bit so just saw this. super kind, and will let you know how i get on.

Comment: Feel free to mark this as your answer, unless something better comes along. Glad to help.

Comment: about to send a test link in 1 min - i need a touch more help to get it working...

Comment: Yes that's as expected, I wouldn't stretch it. The example you have is just narrow. This is the better approach to leave it this way. If you stretch this to fit the box fully it'll look rough to the eyes any text and graphics. Find another example that's truly 4:3 or 16:9 so you can see it work better!

Comment: definitely, but the game area is 3:4 (and it should always show like that). but there shouldnt be any black on the sides, is there any way to get rid of that? .... also why has our padding above and below gone, and the one liner text below - you had helped set that up so well, not sure why it would have stopped showing?

Comment: No I think you got your heights/widths reverse your game area is not 4:3 or 16:9 ratio, it's looking more portrait less rectangular. Looking at your code you have your canvas re-sizing actively and it's incorrect it's not 4:3.

Comment: hmm, i think it's right? the game area (red bg) is proportional to 192x 256 which is 3:4.
yes, the red area is the only thing that should show, not sure why the black areas are showing.
and not sure why the text below, and padding above and below has gone hmmm.

Comment: I  haven't analyzed it fully but there's a conflicts greatly in your code. Ex your aspect-ratio is reversed try 4 / 3 instead and the canvas is outputting a higher height than width so it's not 4:3 at all some confusions. Review your code. :) the iframe-container will size the inner contents make sure the inner contents like iframe/canvas size to this container 100% should solve much of the problem.

Comment: thanks. but the game i want to show is in 3:4 (not 4:3).. so is not what i have correct? it should be vertical. and yes, i will review the code more :)

i just do't understand why it is showing the black sides if we are scaling correctly at 3:4.... and why the padding above/below is not working... or why the text below is not showing. if anyone can help? thank you again

Comment: oh the container has a set width of 70% so if the width of the inner elements are greater it'll prevent over-sizing you can probably take that off and do you ratio as 3 / 4 instead of 4 / 3.  What you want is not really friendly with most wide-displays.

Comment: Your HTML structure isn't favorable, the iframe can contain this element but given you're sizing your iframe to iframe-container element it'd make sense to place the text element below the iframe container like in my example above (the HTML). Also it's not valid HTML the way it is now... looked funny in developer console big-time. :)

Comment: Oh tons of things but that's where UX becomes an endless effort, enjoy; have fun. If this answer helped do approve it.

Answer (score 0):

the solution above worked.
in order for things to scale according to heightl this is how i updated this section of code, so the game is framed correctly (no black borders)

```
.iframe-container {
    /* Define your desired aspect ratio here (e.g., 16:9) */
    aspect-ratio: 3 / 4;
    height: 80%;
}
```

the code may be a bit janky, but it is working for test purposes. thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).